# Stadia Bluetooth UUID

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, hid

To create a drone I want to recycle my stadia bluetooth low energy controller. With a scanner bluetooth I access to UUID for device information or battery level but no way to get the HID or button/joystick UUID. I don't fin either a UUID table on the net.

Do you have a solution to get theses information ?

It's my first project with BLE. Is there a command to enable the HID service ?

Thank you for our answers !

Clément Poisson.

I succed to acces to the information and battery BLE service. I also try to look for the HID UUID with a BLE Scanner, but nothing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a screenshot of all the services you managed to find using your scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Stadia controller with [Bluetooth mode firmware](https://stadia.google.com/controller/) is a BLE HID controller.

You can **press Stadia button and Y button simultaneously** for 2 seconds to enable pairing mode. More info with Wireshark dump [here](https://github.com/DJm00n/ControllersInfo/tree/master/stadiacontroller).

Bluetooth LE is using the Generic Attribute profile (GATT) which defines a service framework using the Attribute Protocol. This framework defines procedures and formats of services and their characteristics. The procedures defined include discovering, reading, writing, notifying and indicating characteristics, as well as configuring the broadcast of characteristics. See Bluetooth Core Specification [Vol 3] Part G for more info.

References on Bluetooth and HID [from bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/):

- [Bluetooth Core Specification 5.4](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-4/)
- [HID Service (HIDS) 1.0](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/human-interface-device-service-1-0/)
- [HID over GATT Profile (HOGP) 1.0](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/hid-over-gatt-profile-1-0/)
- [Bluetooth Assigned Numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) - for a list of UUIDs